# How did French people greet in 1400?

Tags: middle-ages, cultural-history, language

How did French people greet in 1400?

In particular I'm looking for french expressions that a peasant like Saint Joan of Arc could have used to greet a friend.

Comment: Trivia is off topic. Also, this is a question about language, not history.

Comment: How is this not history?

Comment: Actually I can't find an answer even after a few days of research. This is **not** easily answered by looking up the relevant topic on Wikipedia nor any other resource I've access too. I don't think that popular culture can be automatically qualified as trivial. But I get that this is also a language related question. However I can't find a more appropriate place to ask... If a more appropriate site exists on stackexchange that can answer this question please move the question there.

Comment: This is a perfectly good history question. History is not all wars and elections.

Comment: Try the French stack.